# Why is the expression $\frac{I(x>\theta)}{I(x>\theta)}$ independent of $\theta$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, real-numbers

This question has been asked before but I can't really grasp the explanations.

Let $f(x\mid \theta)=\frac{I(x>\theta)}{I(x>\theta)}$ for some particular value of $x$. I want to show that $f$ is independent of $\theta$, but I cannot reconcile this with the fact that if $\theta<X$, then $f=1$, and if $\theta>X$, then $f=\frac{0}{0}$. 
Could someone give me an intuitive and full explanation for why  $ f=\frac{0}{0}=1$ in this scenario?

Comment: Note $\frac{ajfit184mg}{ajfit184mg}=1.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value $0/0$ is somewhat arbitrary. We may assume $0/0 = 1$, in which case $f(x|\theta)$ is indeed independent of $\theta$. But, if we pick $0/0 = 0$, then obviously it depends on $\theta$.

Your source probably assumes $0/0 = 1$.

Comment: The book does assume that $0/0=1$, but I don't feel comfortable using this assumption without understanding it.

Comment: 0/0 is really indeterminate, but we can give it a value for notation convenience.

For example in your example we have without assumptions, $I(x > \theta) f(x | \theta) = I(x > \theta)$. Letting $0/0 = 1$ lets us write is down more compactly as $f(x | \theta) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say $0/0=1$ in this situation.

Suppose it is asserted that $f(x\mid\theta) = \dfrac{g(\theta)}{h(\theta)}$ does not depend on $\theta.$ As long as there is no value of $\theta$ for which $h(\theta)=0,$ that statement is not problematic. And it is equivalent to saying there is some constant $c,$ not depending on $\theta,$ for which $h(\theta) f(x\mid\theta) = c\cdot g(\theta)$ for all values of $\theta.$ And that last statement is probably what was intended.